# How to merge two Javascript objects and ignore properties which are in destination?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, underscore.js

If I have two objects, how to merge them and retain the values of properties in the destination if the same properties exist also in the source? Objects can be different in structure. Preferably using Angular JS or Underscore. Lodash can't be used.

Example:

```
obj1 = {"id": 1, "name": "john"}
obj2 = {"id": "2", "zip": "72623", "city": "London"}. //note id here is a string value where id in obj1 is a number
```

When merged, I want `obj1` to be `{"id": 1, "name": "john", "zip":"72623", "city": "London"}`

I tried: `obj1 = angular.merge({}, obj1, obj2)` but id was "2".

Comment: Did you try spread operator? Take a look at this post - https://medium.com/@mwalterspieler_31762/es6-using-the-spread-operator-to-merge-object-d71c62c98056

Comment: Iterate trhough obj2 with `Object.keys(obj2).forEach(key => ...)` and write your own code to check whether you want to append or skip the property.

Comment: Put obj2 *before* obj1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use **Object.assign()** ...

for example:

```
obj1 = {"id": 1, "name": "john"}
obj2 = {"id": "2", "zip": "72623", "city": "London"}

const ob3 = Object.assign(obj1,obj2) 
//you get 
//{id: "2"
//name: "john"
//zip: "72623"
//city: "London"}
```

or if you do

```
 const ob3 = Object.assign(obj2,obj1);

 // {id: 1
 //zip: "72623"
// city: "London"
// name: "john"
//}
```

Or use **spread operator**

```
const obj3 = {...obj1,...obj2}
```

Or opposite

```
 const obj3 = {...obj2,...obj1}
```

Hope it helps you!!